# Easier method to evaluate integral

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

This question is worth two marks and IMHO (by the method I use) requires too much work to be worth only two marks. So I am wondering if there is a *faster* method to evaluate:

$$I=\int_{-1}^{1}\frac{dx}{1+x^2}$$
Calculator not permitted.
I tried:

$$\text{let }x=\tan\theta\tag{1}$$
$$\therefore1=\sec^2\theta \frac{d\theta}{dx}$$
$$\int_{-1}^{1}\frac{dx}{1+x^2}=\int_{x=-1}^{x=1}\frac{\sec^2\theta}{1+\tan^2\theta} d\theta$$
$$=\int_{x=-1}^{x=1}\frac{\sec^2\theta}{\sec^2\theta} d\theta$$
$$=\int_{x=-1}^{x=1}1\space d\theta$$
$$=\theta\bigm|_{x=-1}^{x=1}$$
and from $(1)$
$$\theta=\tan^{-1}x$$
$$\therefore\theta\bigm|_{x=-1}^{x=1}\space=\tan^{-1}(1)-\tan^{-1}(-1)$$

So by the following triangle:

[image: identity triangle]

$$I=\frac{\pi}{4}- \frac{-\pi}{4}=\frac{\pi}{2}$$

> Can it be done better?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: You’re expected to recognize $\frac1{1+x^2}$ as the derivative of $\tan x$ and get the antiderivative by inspection rather than by doing a trig substitution.

Comment: Ahhh. Thanks for that.

Comment: You’re welcome!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

(To get this off the Unanswered list.)

You’re expected to recognize $\frac1{1+x^2}$ as the derivative of $\arctan x$ and get the antiderivative by inspection rather than by doing a trig substitution.

Comment: @metacompactness: Eep! You are so right; thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Simply use that $$\frac{d}{dx} \arctan x = \frac{1}{1+x^2}.$$